# NSS lib PK11_PrivDecryptPKCS1 function documentation

Tags: c, cryptography, nss

Where can I find the complete documentation for Mozilla's NSS library functions, specially the PK11_PrivDecryptPKCS1 function ?

I can only find a page that leads to the source code, without any explanation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Cryptography_functions

I have some doubts: outLen parameter is written with the decrypted data length ? if so what is the size to malloc so I have enough space on data ?

Comment: Could you test with `outLen` set to zero? Ignore the failure and test what is returned by the API. If I'm not mistaken it will return the required size in `outLen`.

Comment: will do that and brb

Comment: May even work with values higher than 0 actually, in case you already have a buffer.

Comment: the data it's being decifered is 256 bytes long. I tried with a 1024 byte buffer, but it didn't work.

Comment: So you both allocated that memory and put 1024 number in `outLen`? What error did you get? You should not directly encrypt/decrypt data using RSA. You should encrypt/decrypt a random symmetric key and encrypt the data using that (hybrid cryptosystem). What's your keysize and algorithm?

Comment: @Marteen, the only error I get is SECFailure. I tried with 0 and it returned the same. Actually, I don't know much about cryptography. Only a basic course a couple of years ago. I'm trying to maintain am already developed security package that it's not working in ubuntu 14.04. I know C/C++ only. So I was assigned to this task, and I pinpointed the problem in this function. How can I see what is the keysize and algorithm ? the length of the encrypted data passed to the function is 256 bytes.

Comment: I was trying to get the documentation in order to understand better what the function was trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, internet down here, now on 4G (which, funny enough, often beats my 200 Mb/s connection). Documentation of NSS is as bad as the source code. So if Google cannot find it, it probably doesn't exist. Did you ignore the error and look at `outLen` as requested?

Comment: Yes. I already said at the previous comment. The outLen returned 0 and in data it had a couple of bytes 3-4 bytes. This is the data returned in a printf %s:  <E8>k><94>)^?